How can I change the underlying coordinates of a pcolormesh map?
I have a 2D, NxN numpy array (q) that corresponds to a map, expressed in latitudes (b) and longitudes (l). I can generate a meshgrid and plot my map:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
lg, bg = np.meshgrid(l, b)
ax.pcolormesh(lg, bg, q)

However, I need to change the map coordinates to an orthographic projection and then visualize.
This amounts to transforming each coordinate, but this is N^2 computations and could be very expensive for large maps. Is there a quick way to change coordinates of an underlying map?

Have you looked into cartopy?

Not helpful in my case, I need to know how to do the actual computation. If you know if/how cartopy does it, please provide a detailed answer.

Cartopy uses pyproj, which is a python interface to proj.  These are both open source so I guess you can study their code to see how it's done. https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ


Is there a quick way to change coordinates of an underlying map?

No.
If you don't want an approximate solution, you must compute the new position of every point. You or the library you use.
However a library may rely on a binary object produced by an optimizing compiler (Fortran, C++, what else) and hence is probably faster that any pure Python solution.
